# ExceptionInInitializerError in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Because of using the same instances during the whole project I decided to put them in separate class and call them with static methods. The problem is that some of them works well some of them not. Don't understand what is the logic.

I got a class with instances (i know about dagger2 don't worry)

```
public class FirebaseReferences {

   public static FirebaseUser currentUserInstance = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   public static String currentUserUid = currentUserInstance.getUid();

   public static FirebaseUser getCurrentUserInstance(){
       return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   }

    public static DatabaseReference getCurrentUserUidReference(){
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserUid);
    }

    static String getCurrentUserUidString(String uid){
        String currentUid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserUid).toString();
        return currentUid;
    }

    public String getUserToken(){
        return FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    }

}
```

And that the class where I am trying to call getCurrentUserInstance but hot error

```
firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                Log.v("RW", "onAuthStateChanged" );
                if (FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserInstance() != null) {
                    Log.v("RW", "user is not null");
                    //Create new user
                    final String userName = FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserInstance().getDisplayName();          
                    FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserUidReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            //the image is still the default one
                            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                            userMap.put("name", userName);
                            userMap.put("image", "default");
                            userMap.put("thumb_image", "default");
                            userMap.put("status", "Your status is here...");
                            FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserUidReference().setValue(userMap);


                        }
```

The error code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.borisruzanov.russianwives, PID: 19900
              java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                  at com.borisruzanov.russianwives.utils.FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserInstance(FirebaseReferences.java:14)
                  at com.borisruzanov.russianwives.utils.AuthStateListenerUtil$1.onAuthStateChanged(AuthStateListenerUtil.java:34)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.zzi.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
                  at com.borisruzanov.russianwives.utils.FirebaseReferences.<clinit>(FirebaseReferences.java:11)
```

I am not sure but maybe I make a mistake that I am trying to save that inctances in separate class? Or maybe there is better practice how I can do that? But anyway I don't want to copy paste all that instances which are similar in all classes

PS.
I tried to edit code and it works now. But the strange thing is that here `FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();`I use FirebaseUser with a variable without calling static method and it works when I use static it doesn't work. But at the same time in the line `FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserUidReference().` it works with static

```
     public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    Log.v("RW", "onAuthStateChanged" );
                    if (user != null) {
                        Log.v("RW", "user is not null");
                        //Create new user
                        String uid = user.getUid();
                        final String userName = FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserInstance().getDisplayName();

                        FirebaseReferences.getCurrentUserUidReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Comment: Your use of static fields for `currentUserInstance` and `currentUserUid` is not safe.  Static fields are initialized once, when the containing class is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no valid Firebase user logged in via their auth triggers. This can happen if the session has expired, the user is no longer valid or disabled.

Always put a null check before using any user related data

```
if(Firebase.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null){
  //Do your thing
}
```

Basically, your static method getCurrentUserInstance() is returning a null user and you are calling getUserId() on this null reference. Put a null check on the result

Comment: So it will be if in if? Give more explanation please

Comment: No man.... Your static class is holding a reference to a user which has its session expired... Stop using the static references and just use the normal auth methods instead... Stop holding references to users

Comment: Exception in initialization error happens when there's an exception in a static block or a static initializer so your static class is getting called before firebase gets a chance to load and set up

Comment: Stop using your static class and all its methods completely no matter how convenient you think they are, it'll cause leaks and more

Comment: Ok. I did it. But how I can avoid writing the same code everywhere ? Any good variants?

Comment: you can potentially tinker around with weak references and try lazy initializing user reference only when the weak reference is found null. Might work out. Generally speaking i would just resort to what firebase provides, I'm sure they've thought their architecture through and found the current way the best. Maybe it's more typing but it's safer than thinking of all possible scenarios that come around when you try taking a third party library

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use, for example the `currentUserInstance` just simply use it. There is no need to create a `getCurrentUserInstance()` method that returns the same thing. With other words, all those methods declarations can be removed and use only the static fields: `currentUserInstance`, `currentUserUid` and so on.

It doesn't work because you are creating a new instance of `FirebaseAuth` class every time by calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` which is not correct. You only neet to create it once.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = Firebase.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

And now use this `firebaseUser` object to get the `uid` or the `tokenId` or what you else need.

Comment: anyway it doesn't work. I tried both. It only works as I show in the last code

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Also, don't forget to remove those methods. Are not needed.

Comment: Ok. I did it. But how I can avoid writing the same code everywhere ? Any good variants?